# IAM policy for Google storage bucket: google_storage_bucket_iam_binding vs google_storage_bucket_iam_member

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp

What are the differences between resource google_storage_bucket_iam_binding and google_storage_bucket_iam_member other than the amount of people the iam can be assigned to?

I've looked in the docs (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket_iam.html) but I couldn't work out the difference between the aforementioned resources.

Answer (score 8):

`google_storage_bucket_iam_binding` replaces a role's members whereas `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` adds new members to a role.

Let's say you've granted the `roles/editor` role to members `jack` and `jane` in your bucket IAM policy. Applying a `google_storage_bucket_iam_binding` with `members = ["jill"]` would remove `jack` and `jane` from `roles/editor`, whereas doing the same with `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` would result in all three of `jack`, `jane` and `jill` being included in `roles/editor`.

Many other `terraform-gcp-provider` resources apply the same principle, e.g., `google_project_iam_binding`/`google_project_iam_member`.